# A separate relation to the first item in a collection

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to make Doctrine cascade-save a collection of items, while at the same time keeping a reference to the first item separately. Is it even possible? Because the `first_item_id` column (see below) is never filled with any value. I've tried setting it explicitly and using lifecycle callbacks, but still nothing – the column always gets `null` for a newly added item.

I've also tried using the UoW methods:

- `computeChangeSet()`:

  > A managed+dirty entity X@67135 can not be scheduled for insertion
- `recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet()`:

  > Entity X@67135 is not managed. An entity is managed if its fetched from the database or registered as new through EntityManager#persist
- `computeChangeSets()`: no difference.

Simplified code:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="x")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class X
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity=Item::class,
     *     mappedBy="x",
     *     cascade={"persist"},
     *     orphanRemoval=true
     * )
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"sort" = "ASC"})
     * @var Collection<Item>
     */
    protected $items;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Item::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="first_item_id", referencedColumnName="item_id")
     */
    protected ?Item $firstItem = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->items = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /*
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function updateFirstItem(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $items = $this->items->toArray();
        usort($items, fn(Item $a, Item $b) => $a->getSort() <=> $b->getSort());
        $this->firstItem = reset($items) ?: null;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Now that I thought about it, it's impossible in principle. A new entity must be saved first in order to assign a proper foreign key to the items from the collection. And before these items are saved, they have no key to assign as the `first_item_id`. A chicken and egg type of issue.